# How to setup a popup registeration page in wordpress with function.php

Tags: functions, jquery, javascript, user-registration

everyone:

I wonder if there is existing tutorial on how to create a popup registration page in wordpress by utilizing function.php? or is there another way that can do with it?

Thank you!

Comment: What makes this question not a javascript question? Are you asking how to enqueue a script/style?

Comment: I am having trouble find a way to create a popup area within the same page, not a popup page, so I would consider its to be done in javascript. Do you have any idea about it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can add the HTML for the area via [`wp_footer`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer), include the style with [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style), and include the javascript to show/hide the popup with [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

```
wpse90382_popup_function() {
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpse90382_popup_html' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'your_style', get_template_directory_uri() . 'your_stylesheet.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'your_script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'your_javascript.js' );
}
wpse90382_popup_html() {
    ?>
        <div>Your HTML</div>
    <?php
}
if ( some condition )
    wpse90382_popup_function();
```

Comment: sounds deep. I do not have a great coding experience yet, I wonder if there is any existing tutorial express the same method or utilize the similar functions as you stated? If you know, that will be great if you could put the link here, thanks!

Comment: I don't know of any tutorial that would cover the whole thing, but you can definitely find tutorials on each element individually, which should be sufficient for you to determine how to put everything together.

Comment: There, threw some real rough code together for you. Note that that's entirely untested and I wrote it directly into the code editor. Also, don't use `wp_head`, use `wp_footer`. `wp_footer` is within the `<body>` tags.